# installation of bugify in centos

Tags: linux, php, centos

I am trying to install bugify in CentOS server. When I used to install bugify the following error is pulled out:

```
Bugify requires certain binaries to exist on this server in order to run properly.
Could not find the PHP Cli tool at /usr/bin/php.
```

What binaries do I need, and how do I get them?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Your installation

```
Could not find the PHP Cli tool at /usr/bin/php.
```

Presumably that means you need to install it.

---

So you find out which package it's in:

```
yum provides /usr/bin/php
```

And the system tells you it's in the `php-cli` package.

---

So install that now:

```
yum install php-cli
```

Then try your bugify installation again.

Comment: no it doesn't help its shows all packages are installed

Answer (score 0):

Right now it's just complaining for php.

Simply install PHP, using this command

# yum install php -y

After this at least it won't give this error after. Might be some other dependency.

Comment: yum install php -y pops out that already package has been installed

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure php-cli is installed, perhaps the path is not `/usr/bin/php` (Bugify checks at both `/usr/bin/php` and `/usr/local/bin/php`).

From SSH, what does the output of `which php` and `php -v` say?